# yolov5 not working when typing sudo yolov5 detect

Tags: importerror, traceback, yolov5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPi5W.jpg)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 23, in 
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec, Self, TypeAlias
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall `typing_extensions`.

`pip uninstall typing_extensions`

- Install the latest version

`pip install typing-extensions==4.9.0`

Comment: pi@raspberry:~ $ pip uninstall typing_extensions 
Found existing installation: typing-extensions 3.7.4.3
Not uninstalling typing-extensions at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'typing-extensions'. No files were found to uninstall.
pi@raspberry:~ $

Comment: That means that `typing_extensions` was not installed. Can you try installing it? (use the latest version i provided (:

Comment: nothing change. the error still the same

Comment: Can we verify installation?

`pip show typing-extensions` or `pip3 show typing-extensions`

Comment: Let me know what the version is

Comment: i tried installing it and run again the yolo but same error again

Comment: did some digging. there are problems with raspberry pi 3b model. can you try with a lower version

`pip install typing-extensions==4.3.0`

Comment: pi@raspberry:~ $ pip3 show typing-extensions
Name: typing-extensions
Version: 3.7.4.3
Summary: Backported and Experimental Type Hints for Python 3.5+
Home-page: https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/README.rst
Author: Guido van Rossum, Jukka Lehtosalo, Lukasz Langa, Michael Lee
Author-email: levkivskyi@gmail.com
License: PSF
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: torch, huggingface-hub

I use the old 64 bit os bullseye because I am following a video tutorial on youtube

Comment: i am using raspberry pi4b and here is my os 2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-arm64

i am following freedom tech youtube tutorial and everything was smooth until I run the command on sudo yolov5 detect

Comment: Install the lower version with the command I provided. then do the `show` command again

Comment: should i install it the python3.9 directory or just in the terminal?

Comment: i installed the lower version and nothing happened, same error

Comment: Not the error. did the version change?

Comment: oww, sorry. yes it change to 4.3.0

Comment: pip3 show typing-extensions
Name: typing-extensions
Version: 4.3.0

Comment: help please people

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?